# printing test grades and test score average within functions using python

Tags: python, function, if-statement, input, average

The assignment is to get 5 test score and use them to display the corresponding letter grade and test score average using functions. I don't know if I'm on the right track and I was having trouble calling the other functions within the main function.

```
def main():
        s1 = int(input('Enter score one: '))
        s2 = int(input('Enter score two: '))
        s3 = int(input('Enter score three: '))
        s4 = int(input('Enter score four: '))
        s5 = int(input('Enter score five: '))
    return s1, s2, s3, s4, s5
    
    test_grade = determine_grade(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5)
    print(test_grade)
    
    average_num = calc_average(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5)
    print(average_num)

    
def calc_average(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5):
    average = s1 + s2 + s3 +s4 +s5 / 5
    return average


def determine_grade(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5):
    if (90 <= s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 <= 100):
        grade_a = "A"
        return grade_a
    elif (80 <= s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 <= 89):
        grade_b = "B"
        return grade_b
    elif (70 <= s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 <= 79):
        grade_c = "C"
        return grade_c
    elif (60 <= s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 <= 69):
        grade_d = "D"
        return grade_d
    elif (s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 < 60):
        grade_f = "F"
        return grade_f

main()
```

Comment: You have dead code. The code after the return never gets executed and I think that's what troubles you. Also `determine_grade` won't work. You probably need `sum([s1, s2, s3, s4, s5])`

Comment: `return` causes a function to exit.  So `main()` stops executing once it sees the `return s1, s2, s3, s4, s5` line.

Comment: `return`  should be at the end after the function calls

Comment: Your `if` statements have incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`return` should be at the end of the main function

```
def main():
        s1 = int(input('Enter score one: '))
        s2 = int(input('Enter score two: '))
        s3 = int(input('Enter score three: '))
        s4 = int(input('Enter score four: '))
        s5 = int(input('Enter score five: '))
    
    
        test_grade = determine_grade(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5)
        print(test_grade)
    
        average_num = calc_average(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5)
        print(average_num)
        return s1, s2, s3, s4, s5
```

You were missing brackets in average that's why it was giving wrong average

```
def calc_average(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5):
    average = (s1 + s2 + s3 +s4 +s5) / 5
    return average
```

Your `if` syntax was wrong for comparing all values.

```
def determine_grade(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5):
    if all(item >= 90 and item <= 100 for item in (s1, s2, s3 ,s4 ,s5)):
        grade_a = "A"
        return grade_a
    elif all(item >= 80 and item <= 89 for item in (s1, s2, s3 ,s4 ,s5)):
        grade_b = "B"
        return grade_b
    elif all(item >= 70 and item <= 79 for item in (s1, s2, s3 ,s4 ,s5)):
        grade_c = "C"
        return grade_c
    elif all(item >= 60 and item <= 69 for item in (s1, s2, s3 ,s4 ,s5)):
        grade_d = "D"
        return grade_d
    else :
        grade_f = "F"
        return grade_f

main()
```